# Unable to create postgresql view connecting different databases - odoo 11

Tags: python-3.x, database, postgresql, odoo-11

Unable to create view(postgresql) connecting and fetching data from different databases in Odoo v11.

Creating a view by fetching data from local(logged in) database works fine, but when I connect to a different database to fetch data the view is not created in current database.

```
def run_query_live(self):
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='****_live' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='******'")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("""CREATE VIEW inl_data_apex AS (SELECT * from table)""")
```

when I directly execute query with self.env.cr.execute, I am able to see the view created in current logged in database.

But when I connect it to different database, could not see the view in either of the database.

Comment: `CREATE VIEW` only creates a view in the PostgreSQL `dbname`/`host` combination you currently connected to (which, in your example, is `****_live` and `localhost`).  If you choose any other database, you will need to re-create the view for that `dbname`/`host` combination

Comment: @richyen Thanks for the input. I want that view created in current database not on the connected database. But the data I want is in connected DB only. How to create such view???

Comment: I think what you’re looking for is a foreign data wrapper (FDW) https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html